# java servlet google in app payment

Tags: java, web, in-app-purchase

I have studied the java in app billing code snippet at

https://developers.google.com/in-app-payments/docs/tutorial

and I am unable to use it to make my application capable of doing in app payments.

My first question is how do I set up a servlet to handle payment requests. Do I put the getJWT() method in the servlet and call it from the doPost() method?

My second question is what do I do with the String that getJWT() returns? It should be the json object that holds the purchasing information, but I don't know how the jsp file I have should process it.

I have searched for example code using java servlets and jsps to study but found none. I have found python code, but I can't translate python into java yet. If anyone knows of an example (complete) of google in app billing using java servlets and jsps I would appreciate it if you could post a link also.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

On the server you need an HttpServlet derived class that takes the order request (in doPost()), calls the JWT libraries together with the Seller Secret to generate the signed JWT string, then returns the result in the response.

On the client side in the HTML page you can use a templating system (e.g. AppEngine + JSPs) or Ajax calls to your servlet to get the generated JWT.

The generated JWT is one of the paramenters to the goog.payments.inapp.buy() JavaScript API.

Below is a simple AppEngine Python implementation of In-App Payments. You can re-use the client-side code and replace the server-side with the Java implementation:

https://code.google.com/p/iap-python/